# Can you get the connection state of a socket programmatically?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking, winsock

You can get a connection state using the `netstat` command (a connection state is something like `ESTABLISHED` or `TIME_WAIT` and so on).

But can you get the connection state of a socket programmatically?

Comment: Sure: if you haven't connected yet, it's connecting; if you have connected, it's established; etc. States like TIME_WAIT occur after you close the socket, IIRC, so there is no socket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't query a `SOCKET` itself for the kind of state you are wanting.

But, you *can* query the socket for its type (TCP vs UDP) and IP/Port pairs assigned to it (ie, via [`getsockopt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockopt) with [SO_BSP_STATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-bsp-state), or via `getsockopt(SO_TYPE)` +[`getsockname()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockname)+[`getpeername()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getpeername)), and then you can enumerate Windows' TCP/UDP tables until you find an entry that matches those same details, then you will have the state from that entry.

Have a look at the following enumeration functions:

TCP:

- [`GetTcpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable)/[`GetTcpTable2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable2) (IPv4 only)
- [`GetTcp6Table()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcp6table)/[`GetTcp6Table2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcp6table2) (IPv6 only)
- [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedtcptable) (both IPv4 and IPv6)

UDP:

- [`GetUdpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudptable) (IPv4 only)
- [`GetUdp6Table()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudp6table) (IPv6 only)
- [`GetExtendedUdpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedudptable) (both IPv4 and IPv6)

Answer (score -2):

On Windows, you can use [`getsockopt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockopt) with the [`SO_BSP_STATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-bsp-state) option to get at least *some* information about the state of a socket:

> The `SO_BSP_STATE` socket option returns the local address, local port,
> remote address, remote port, socket type, and protocol used by a
> socket.
>
> To perform this operation, call the `getsockopt` function with the
> following parameters.
>
> Socket option value The constant that represents this socket option is
> 0x1009.
>
> **Syntax**
> C++
>
> ```
> int getsockopt(
>    (SOCKET) s,         // descriptor identifying a socket
>    (int) SOL_SOCKET,   // level
>    (int) SO_BSP_STATE, // optname
>    (char *) optval,    // output buffer,
>    (int) *optlen,      // size of output buffer );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *s* [in]
>
> A descriptor identifying the socket.
>
> *level* [in]
>
> The level at which the option is defined. Use SOL_SOCKET for this
> operation.
>
> *optname* [in]
>
> The socket option for which the value is to be retrieved. Use
> `SO_BSP_STATE` for this operation.
>
> *optval* [out]
>
> A pointer to the buffer in which the value for the requested option is
> to be returned. This parameter should point to buffer equal to or
> larger than the size of a `CSADDR_INFO` structure.
>
> *optlen* [in, out]
>
> A pointer to the size, in bytes, of the optval buffer. This size must
> be equal to or larger than the size of a `CSADDR_INFO` structure.
>
> **Return value**
>
> If the operation completes successfully, `getsockopt`
> returns zero.
>
> If the operation fails, a value of `SOCKET_ERROR` is returned and a
> specific error code can be retrieved by calling `WSAGetLastError`.

A [`CSADDR_INFO` structure is defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-csaddr_info) as

```
typedef struct _CSADDR_INFO {
  SOCKET_ADDRESS LocalAddr;
  SOCKET_ADDRESS RemoteAddr;
  INT            iSocketType;
  INT            iProtocol;
} CSADDR_INFO, *PCSADDR_INFO, *LPCSADDR_INFO;
```

Comment: `SO_BSP_STATE` does not provide the state that the OP is looking for.  But, it can be used as a 1st step to getting that info from another API. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73325984/65863) for those APIs.